# Can I filter a column relative to the max value in that column?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to create a measure that is the sum of the last 7 days with sales data.

The following code only works as desired when sales data is recent and there are no date filters that clash.

```
CALCULATE([Sold Dollars], 
          'calendar'[Date] <= TODAY()-1) && 'calendar'[Date] >= TODAY()-7)
```

I tried this code:

```
CALCULATE([Sold Dollars], 
          'calendar'[Date] <= MAX('calendar'[Date])-1
          && 'calendar'[Date] >= MAX('calendar'[Date])-7)
```

But it returns an error message:

> A function 'MAX' has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed.

What can I do to create a measure that is filtered to the top seven ALLSELECTED dates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to do it.

To avoid the error message you received, you can save max date in a variable, and then use it as a filter condition in CALCULATE.

Or, you can use this approach:

```
Seven Day Sales =
VAR 
  Latest_Date = MAX ( 'calendar'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Sold Dollars],
        DATESINPERIOD ( 'calendar'[Date], Latest_Date, -7, DAY )
    )
```

You can adjust the calculation of the "Latest_Date" variable to your needs.

Comment: Now when I use the variable in a measure, the measure is filtered by all the same filters I used to calculate the variable. For example if want the Latest_Date where only customer x has sales data to limit the sold dollars measure it will only return sold dollars for customer x, is there a way around that?

Comment: I circumvented the problem by creating a boolean calculated column in my `'Calendar'` table using the latest_date measure, and filtered other measures using the calculated column.